# XDoclet and JBoss in MyEclipse

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0, myeclipse, xdoclet

I have installed MyEclipse 9.1 (installed from pulse using Eclipse Helios) and I need to integrate with JBoss.

I can see in Servers that JBoss is present till version 6, but when I do properties of the project to add XDoclet from MyEclipse -> XDoclet -> Add Standard, and I add StandardEJB I cannot find JBoss???

Does anyone have any idea If I missing integration between MyEclipse and Jboss???

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MyEclipse Help at MyEclipse Learning Center->EJB Development->Getting Started->EJB 2.x Tutorial (Using XDoclet), section 7.1.2 shows how to add application server specific subdoclets, with a JBoss example. If that doesn't help, I suggest raising it on their forums for better support, giving exact details of what you're trying to do.